# Como redireccionar puertos de diferentes dominios a diferentes servidores

Tags: tcp, iptables, redirección

Tengo dos aplicaciones con la siguiente arquitectura:
Dos dominios que se conectan a la misma ip por https y es resuelto por un tomcat configurado con dos host (

```
Dominio1.com \                                   / Spring Dominio1 (192.168.0.3) :2000, :2001
               :443                        :1099
                    \                    /
                      Tomcat 192.168.0.2
                    /                    \
               :443                        :1099
Dominio2.com /                                   \ Spring Dominio2 (192.168.0.4) :2000, :2001
```

Adicional en los BackEnds (Spring) tengo unos puertos adicionales (2000, 2001) no http, son sokets TCP, UDP.

¿Es posible configurar 'algo'? En 192.168.0.2 para que al consumir Dominio1.com:2000 me retorne 192.168.0.3:2000 y Dominio2.com:2000 me retorne 192.168.0.4:2000.